# Cakephp pagination formatting first and last ugliness

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I am using the number class for cakephp to manage some basic pagination. This is the pagination link that I created

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 'First', 'last' => 'Last', 'modulus' => 20)); ?>
```

On the page this will print the following:

```
First14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34Last
```

Notice that the `|` divider will not print between First and 14 and also 34 and Last. The docs make it seem like this functionality should be in the default, and no matter how I tinker with my pagination options I cannot make that `|` appear. Does anyone know what would fix this, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thank you.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that this would be the default behavior?

Comment: While the docs never say this explicitly, this seems like a weird way to display this information.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper

Comment: I was just wondering, it would have helped determining whether this is a bug. The behaviour is indeed a little odd, and unfortunately using strings for `last` and `before` is not covered by tests, only using integers is, so it's hard to tell how this is ment to behave. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/a90cb29c0f6f40b1605f97f0bba8bc74fff70955/lib/Cake/View/Helper/PaginatorHelper.php#L725) gives me headaches, there seem to be cases where it adds the separator, but especially the use of `$first` as a number where it could be a string confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problems so I did it per hand. This is my paginator-code which I use on all of my pages

```
= $this->Paginator->first('<<')
= '&nbsp;'              
= $this->Paginator->prev('<')
= '&nbsp;'
= $this->Paginator->numbers(array('seperator' => '|'))
= '&nbsp;'      
= $this->Paginator->next('>')
= '&nbsp;'
= $this->Paginator->last('>>')
```

Probably not the "nicest" code, but it works and gives a full working Paginator. In your case you would change the << / >> to First/Last and remove the prev/next Entries

Hope this helps